# How do I set idle timeout on SQL Report server (SSRS)

Tags: sql, reporting-services, timeout, ssrs-2012

I am trying to stop the service going into shutdown, so that next time its used, it doesnt take 2 mins to load.

Unfortunately I cannot find where to alter such settings, as the report server to my suprise is NOT hosted on IIS. It has some sort of native host.

How can I edit the timeout. Below is what an IIS timeout setting looks like.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would create a simple "Warmup report", then schedule it to run every 30 minutes or so.

Comment: Seems more of a hack than a solution. but +1 as i suppose it would work. Not what im looking for though

Comment: any full source code about it ? not solution using SSRS configuration ?